# Retrieving an image to my UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uiimageview

I load the image using my Android application Parse in my database, and I want to show it on my iphone.

when I run the Xcode tells me: 'Could not release the value of type' NSConcreteData 'to' PFFile ''

there any way to get this image and show on my iPhone (UIImageView) ??

Any idea to help me ?

I'll be very grateful !!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvrvO.png)

Comment: the problem is, that your object["profile picture"] is NSData and not PFFile

Comment: dude whats going on? people are investing their time trying to help you so at least answer

Comment: sorry, I'm without my mac, and completely forgot.
and I managed to do today

Comment: I just used "let getParseImg NSData = [" image "]  as! NSData" and without using the function "getDataInBackgroundWithBlock"

Comment: okay. but then please close the question so people dont waste their time thinking about your problem. glad you got it working

Comment: always remember. people are investing their time in exchange for upvotes and "check as answered"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, as the Compiler tells you, that you're trying to cast NSData to PFFile.

Just use:

```
    let userImageProfilePicture = event["profile_picture"]
    userImageProfilePicture.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (data, error) -> Void in

          // handle here with your userAuth == true block

          if let data = data where error == nil{
              var image = UIImage(data: data)
          }
    })
```

Comment: sorry for delay to answer you, I'm without my MAC
I tested now and your code worked, but I also got with
let getParseImg NSData = [" image "] as! NSData, without using the function "getDataInBackgroundWithBlock"

Comment: okay but since my answered worked for you as well, you could accept my answer or am i right? :)